# Array of std::function with different argument type

Tags: c++, event-handling, signals

I'm trying to design my own implementation of Signal Bus using C++.

To reach my goals I'm using a vector of *std::function<void()>* callbacks for free functions or lambdas. For example, if we need to subscribe to some event (just an empty struct) we can use lambda expression:

```
SignalBus->Subscribe<FirstSignal>([&] { MethodA(); });
```

or we can pass function as sargument if we're speaking about static/free functions.

This case works great, but sometimes we need to send some data with event. This is the place where I'm stuck. My idea is to use structs to pass data to event-callback and my first approach was to declare an EventBase class and use polymorphism:

```
std::function<void(EventBase)>
```

but it didn't work with derived structs/classes because there's no convertion between struct EventBase and struct DerivedEvent : public EventBase. It's obvious. Then I decided to use void pointer to function:

```
std::function<void(void*)>
```

It works, but if you want to subscribe to some event using this method you need to type this weird code:

```
SignalBus->SubscribeWithData<SecondSignal>([&](void* signal) {
    auto data = (SecondSignal*) signal;
    MethodB(*data);} );
```

So we're capturing object reference, take void* parameter and then make C-style cast to provide raw conversion of types.

It's ok, it works, but it's awful and it's not okay to type this everytime you need to subscribe, so here's my question: Is there any options to make it work better with easy-to-use for end user?

Different kinds of casting of std::function; std::any;

Comment: Is it obvious? You need pointers/references for polymorphism, else there is object slicing.

Comment: Remember that for polymorphism, you need either pointer or references to the base class. So instead of `void(EventBase)` try `void(EventBase&)` or `void(EventBase*)`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude at this point i need to make all my events to be derived from base class. Anything else? I need some flexibility

Comment: whats wrong about deriving from an `EventBase`?

Comment: Why do you need to store all handlers in the same vector in the first place? Every event can have its own vector of appropriately typed `std::function`.

Comment: There are many signaling frameworks available for C++ (Qt, Boost, and many standalone libraries and frameworks). If you don't want to use any of them you could always take a look at how they solve this problem.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I would like to use simple data for events without any additional customization. Like in ECS - component is just a struct.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number as far as I know, deriving is not a popular technic in signal bus events

Comment: For those, who suggested using BaseEvent: I just tried to use std::function<void(EventBase*)> and got cannot convert 'ClassA::ClassA()::<lambda(SecondSignal*)>' to 'std::function<void(SignalBase*)>'

Comment: *"would like to use simple data"* Well, type erasure (a fancy word for what you're trying to do) adds complexity too.

Comment: Your post starts with inheritance and the only reason it is discarded is because "it didn't work". In your quesiton you write "..sometimes we need to send some data with event" now you say "events without any additional customization". It is unclear what you actually want.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I mean I it’s not okay if we need to declare event as a struct or class with specific logic and signature inside. As for me, the best option is data only structs, but I can’t deal with storing callbacks